# how to train a model on the text data to produce json response

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers

I have raw text like this.

> amazon.n Tax Invoice/Bill of Supply/Cash Memo (Original for Recipient) Digitally Signed by DS CLOUDTAIL INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED 1 Date: 2020.01.07 08:29:06 UTC Reason: Invoice Sold By : Cloudtail India Private Limited Billing Address : Jay Dhariwal Hauz Khas Building No. 5, BGR Warehousing Complex, Near Shiv Sagar Hotel, Village Vahuli, Bhiwandi, BHIWANDI, MAHARASHTRA, 421302 House No 8 Ground Floor, Block 1 Indraprastha apartments, Indian Institute of Technology Delhi, Thane IN NEW DELHI, DELHI, 110016 IN State/UT Code: 07 Shipping Address : Jay Dhariwal Payal Dhariwal PAN No: AAQCS4259Q GST Registration No: 27AAQCS4259Q1ZA IP-08, Indraprastha apartment road, Indian Institute of Technology Delhi, Hauz Khas NEW DELHI, DELHI, 110016 State/UT Code: 07 Place of supply: DELHI Place of delivery: DELHI Invoice Number : BOM7-5118062 Invoice Details : MH-BOM7-1004-1920 Invoice Date : 07.01.2020 Tax Tax Tax Total Amount RateType/Amount Amount 18% IGST IN Order Number: 171-5358343-0343503 Order Date: 07.01.2020 SI. Description No TOTAL: Amount in Words: Unit Qty Net Price 3335.59 10 1 xcluma Hc-05 Wireless Bluetooth Rf Transceiver Module Serial/TU/Rs232 Arduino B071HWFYJP ( B071HWFYJP) ) Three Thousand Nine Hundred And Sixty only 33,355.90 3604.10 33,960.00 3604.10,33.960.00 For Cloudtail India Private Limited: Authorized Signatory Whether tax is payable under reverse charge - No Seller Services Pvt. Ltd., India Pvt. Ltd. (only where note thatt thisi invoicei is nota a demand for payment Retail India Pvt. Ltd. center is co-located) Customers desirous of availing input GST credit are requested to create al Business account and purchase on Amazon. in/business from Business eligible offers Pa

I have extracted this texts from a pdf of amazon invoice. I have converted this into json form using ChatGPT. which looks like this. I have defined a specific structure for the JSON and used ChatGPT to generate the desired result.

```
{
    "invoice": {
        "invoice_number": "BOM7-5118062",
        "invoice_date": "07.01.2020",
        "irn": "",
        "acknowledgement": {
            "ack_number": "",
            "ack_date": ""
        },
        "customer_details": {
            "name": "Jay Dhariwal",
            "contact": "",
            "address": "House No 8 Ground Floor, Block 1 Indraprastha apartments, Indian Institute of Technology Delhi, Thane",
            "gstin": "27AAQCS4259Q1ZA",
            "pan": "AAQCS4259Q",
            "state": "MAHARASHTRA",
            "state_code": "27"
        },
        "order_details": {
            "order_number": "171-5358343-0343503",
            "order_date": "07.01.2020"
        },
        "delivery_agent": {
            "name": ""
        },
        "payment_terms": "",
        "place_of_supply": "DELHI",
        "items": [
            {
                "description": "xcluma Hc-05 Wireless Bluetooth Rf Transceiver Module Serial/TU/Rs232 Arduino B071HWFYJP ( B071HWFYJP) )", 
                "hsn_sac": "",
                "quantity": "10",
                "rate_per_unit": "3335.59",
                "amount": "33960.00"
            }
        ],
        "taxes": {
            "cgst_rate": "",
            "sgst_rate": "",
            "cgst_amount": "",
            "sgst_amount": "",
            "total_tax": "3604.10"
        },
        "total_amount": "33960.00",
        "amount_in_words": "Three Thousand Nine Hundred And Sixty only",
        "supplier_details": {
            "gstin": "",
            "pan": "",
            "bank_details": {
                "branch": "",
                "ifsc_code": ""
            }
        },
        "terms_conditions": []
    }
}
```

How can I train a model to automate the system of extracting text from PDFs and converting them into JSON without relying on the OpenAI API key to avoid incurring costs? I have a large number of text files and their corresponding JSON files. Are there any alternative methods or frameworks I can use to train a model that can generate similar JSON data? I prefer not to rely on ChatGPT. Any suggestions ?

I have attempted to fine-tune a BERT model specifically for extracting the 'total_amount' from text using Hugging Face's library. However, I'm encountering issues where the code is not yielding satisfactory results. I'm unsure of what might be causing this problem. Can someone please help me identify the issue with my code and suggest potential improvements for achieving better results?
this was the code.

```
import os
import json
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AdamW
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

# Define the dataset class
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, text_files, json_files, tokenizer):
        self.text_files = text_files
        self.json_files = json_files
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.text_files)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text_file = self.text_files[idx]
        json_file = self.json_files[idx]

        with open(text_file, 'r') as file:
            text = file.read()

        with open(json_file, 'r') as file:
            json_data = json.load(file)

        label_str = json_data['invoice']['total_amount']
        label = float(label_str.replace(',', ''))  # Remove comma and convert to float

        encoded_input = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            text,
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            max_length=512,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )
        return {
            'input_ids': encoded_input['input_ids'].squeeze(),
            'attention_mask': encoded_input['attention_mask'].squeeze(),
            'labels': torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.float)
        }


# Load the pretrained tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=1)  # Set num_labels=1 for regression

# Define hyperparameters
batch_size = 8
learning_rate = 1e-5
num_epochs = 10

# Define the paths to your text files and corresponding JSON files
text_files_dir = 'D:\\finsights\\kitaab-invoice-extractor-converter-api\\texts'
json_files_dir = 'D:\\finsights\\kitaab-invoice-extractor-converter-api\\jsons'

# Get the list of text and JSON files
text_files = [os.path.join(text_files_dir, file) for file in os.listdir(text_files_dir)]
json_files = [os.path.join(json_files_dir, file) for file in os.listdir(json_files_dir)]

# Create dataset and data loader
dataset = MyDataset(text_files, json_files, tokenizer)
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Set device (CPU or GPU)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)

# Set optimizer and loss function
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()  # Use Mean Squared Error (MSE) for regression

# Training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    for batch in data_loader:
        input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
        labels = batch['labels'].to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        loss = outputs.loss
        total_loss += loss.item()

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    avg_loss = total_loss / len(data_loader)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {avg_loss:.4f}')

# Save the trained model
model.save_pretrained("trained-invoices")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("trained-invoices")
```

Comment: Hey @KJ! first of all thankyou for your suggestion. I agree, but this is just an example I'm not going to do financial task which depends on OCR and another thing it will just auto populate the data the person who is filling that will verify first. I just wanted to know that can anyone give me an example how can I train a model on raw text and json data. any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: if you can provide me any source, where can learn how to fine-tune a pretrained model as in my case, that will also work for me. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry, you're not just going to train a BERT model and expect to get that kind of JSON output. Use the ChatGPT API (extremely cheap) or look into distilling GPT-2/GPT-J/GPT-NeoX.